# PageTabBarController Material not as rootviewcontroller

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

Using the example found here:

https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/PageTabBarController

How can I reproduce this without making any of the viewcontrollers as the root viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Material 2.8.0](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.8.0) replaces this component with the `TabsController` and you can try a [sample TabsController project](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/TabsController). As well, the TabsController is a UIViewController, so you can treat it as such. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Ill be sure to try this. Hopefully I'll get some success